# How to change default message of reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'd like to change default error message of reCAPTCHA plugin from "Incorrect Security Image Response". How I can do that?
I'm using PHP and CI framework.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a [custom translation](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html) to replace the text.

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   custom_translations : { incorrect_try_again : "You did it wrong, try again." }
};
</script>
```

Comment: So, I should put those script in a view that using reCAPTCHA right,.?

Comment: Yes. The documentation that I've linked to shows you how to use it.

Comment: hi Tom, I don't understand, why it doesn't make any change, I've put this code `<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
   custom_translations : {
    incorrect_try_again : "Kode yang anda masukan salah, silahkan coba lagi.",
   }
 };
</script>` instead of <head> tag, but it still return `"Incorrect Security Image Response"` can you help me,.?